# PowerShell remote event log parsing

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I wrote a small script to grab event log entries from a remote machine and write it to a .csv file. The script works when targeting a single machine, but when I try to implement a for loop and loop it over all machines in Active Directory, I get this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer] 
does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At Y:\srp.ps1:7 char:143
+ ... | Export-Csv $($computer + ".csv")
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Export-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. 
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At Y:\srp.ps1:7 char:141
+ ... 0 | Export-Csv $($computer + ".csv")
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv],
                              ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,
                              Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

The error indicates there's a problem with the Export-Csv command, but running the command by itself creates the log files needed. Here is the full script, for reference:

```
# Gets SRP event log entries from remote machine and writes them to a .csv file 
# of the same name.

Write-Output "Running..."

$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter {(Name -like "PC*") -or (Name -like "LT*")}
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Microsoft-Windows-SoftwareRestrictionPolicies 
    -ComputerName $computer -Newest 10 | Export-Csv $($computer + ".csv")
} #end foreach

Write-Host "Done."
```

Any ideas as to why this error appears when I try to loop over computers in AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Get-ADComputer` returns `ADComputer` objects, but you're passing it to `Get-EventLog`'s `ComputerName` parameter, which takes a string, as-is. I'm assuming you'll need to grab the name property from the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer` object.

Comment: That was it! I piped `Get-ADComputer` with `Select-Object` and was able to pull PC names correctly.  
    
Full code:  

`$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter {(Name -like "ITCPC*") -or (Name -like "ITCLT*")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`